# Sending messages from various IP-adresses to a single server using Java

Tags: java, networking, proxy, routes

My issue is a protocol that identifies terminals by it's sending IP. I want to manage the connections of several terminals to this server using some kind of proxy that implements that protocol.

So I have Terminal A which is identified by the server by the IP 1.2.3.4 and Terminal B which is identified by the server using the IP 5.6.7.8. Now the proxy will be in a local network with Terminal A and B.

When Terminal A wants to reach the server, it will query the proxy and the proxy needs to send the request on behalf of Terminal A using IP 1.2.3.4 to the server
When Terminal B wants to reach the server, it will query the proxy and the proxy needs to send the request on behalf of Terminal A using IP 5.6.7.8 to the server

Is it even possible to solve that issue in Java or do I have to do network voodoo on the router to achieve this?

Edit: to make things clear. I know what a network proxy is and what a router does. I also know how to solve my problem on a network level using advanced network voodoo if required. What I want to know is if my guess that the problem can't be solved using Java is correct. So the bottom line question is: can I use Java to send traffic using a specific network interface to which a specific IP has been assigned or do I have to rely on what the operating system does to route my traffic (in which case the advanced network voodoo would be required)?

Edit2: If routing of network traffic can be done in java, I'd just like a quick pointer where to look into. My own googling didn't return any useful results.

Comment: There is a difference between a router and a proxy. A Router will not change the source IP address of the connection, a proxy will. What is the intended benefit of this proxy? What will it do?

Comment: Ok so do u basically want to implement a proxy server which will redirect your messages to main server

Comment: Ok, so the reason for this is the following. The terminals already exist and the have a specific purpose (giving money to customers). Those terminals support a multitude of protocols to support different bank backends. That's why a proxy exists in front of them handling those bank backends. Until now all the protocols supported identified the terminals via a unique ID. The new protocol we want to support doesn't have such an ID and identifies the terminals via their IP (so each terminal is required to have a public IP).

Comment: @bakriOnFire: yes, but as stated I need that proxy server to reply using a different network connection for each terminal it proxies to emulate them being different for the server. Since I can't touch the protocol nor the server, I have to solve the issue on the proxies end.

So what I need are means to select the network interface when sending a request in Java.

Answer (score 1):

1) You already have some implementations for tcp tunelling with java. Below are some examples:

- http://jtcpfwd.sourceforge.net/
- http://sourceforge.net/projects/jttt/

2) Even with these existing implementations, you can still do you own by forwarding packets arriving in the proxy using java.net.Socket.

3) I still think that a better option would be a specific implementation using java.lang.Runtime.exec() and *socat* linux command. socat is just like the Netcat but with security and chrooting support and works over various protocols and through a files, pipes, devices, TCP sockets, Unix sockets, a client for SOCKS4, proxy CONNECT, or SSL etc. To redirect all port 80 conenctions to ip 202.54.1.5:

```
$ socat TCP-LISTEN:80,fork TCP:202.54.1.5:80
```

Comment: I think my usage of the word proxy made people misinterpret my question. I don't want to proxy a tcp connection to forward packages.
What I really have is a server speaking to the terminal using protocol A which is then talking as a client to another server using protocol B making it look to the second server like if it were talking to the terminal directly to emulate the terminal speaking a protocol it doesn't actually support.

Comment: Now I need that server to support a new protocol that isn't identifying terminals by an ID transmitted by the protocol, but by the connection thus I need the "proxy" to handle multiple network interfaces while acting as a client towards the server when sending requests, since terminals are identified by the server by their IP!

Comment: Will public Socket(InetAddress address,
              int port,
              InetAddress localAddr,
              int localPort) allow me to route the traffic over the respective network interface when setting the localAddr to the respective IP?
If so I would accept your answer as the right one ...
Have a +1 in the mean time for your effort.